# Interacting with items on a listview within adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an adapter that takes in an array list of String, full of a bunch of different names. As of right now, it displays all the names in the listview properly, but I can't get the checkbox to work properly. To test it, I made a Toast that should displays the person's name when the checkbox is cicked. However, it always displays the name of the last person on the list, regardless of which checkbox I press. The checkbox is going to eventually change a setting for the specific person. I know I'm misunderstanding how adapters work, but I'm not sure where.

```
public class SummonerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
TextView summonerNameText;
String summonerName;
CheckBox checkBox;

public SummonerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> summoners) {
    super(context, 0, summoners);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());     //inflates layout
    View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
    summonerName = getItem(position);
    summonerNameText = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.summonerName);
    summonerNameText.setText(summonerName);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) theView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), summonerNameText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return theView;
}
```

}

Comment: i use an array for all the list items data and modify the array when i do changes to items. Then in the adapter where you display the list items i get the data from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question perfectly i had the same problem i couldn't find a better answer. Try to fill your answers on a List

```
public class SummonerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
final TextView summonerNameText;
final String summonerName;
final CheckBox checkBox;

public SummonerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> summoners) {
    super(context, 0, summoners);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());     //inflates layout
    final View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
    summonerName = getItem(position);
    summonerNameText = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.summonerName);
    summonerNameText.setText(summonerName);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) theView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), summonerNameText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return theView;
}
```

Comment: Setting all of them as final did the trick! But I'm not exactly sure what making them final does?